# Having issues with unindent error in python

Tags: python, indentation

```
  def linear_probe(self, value, start_index):
    hashed_key = start_index % len(self.table)
    while self.table[hashed_key] is not None:
      hashed_key = (hashed_key + 1) % len(self.table)
    return hashed_key, value`enter code here`
```

Hi here is my code for linear_probe function that I'm using in a lab, however for some reason I keep getting the unindent does not match any outer indentation level. however from how  I can see my tabbing looks good as well as there are no white spaces

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely mixing tabs and spaces.

Please make sure your editor is always using spaces.

If possible, let your editor highlight tabs.

Comment: Thanks i checked my tabbing and spacing and made sure I'm not using space but rather only tabbing and no luck

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted has a 2-space indentation for the whole function. Remove 2 spaces from the front of each line and try again:

```py
## <-- accidental indent?
  def linear_probe(self, value, start_index):
    hashed_key = start_index % len(self.table)
    while self.table[hashed_key] is not None:
      hashed_key = (hashed_key + 1) % len(self.table)
    return hashed_key, value`enter code here`
```